# Google Adsense before/above article in Wordpress: SEO problem?

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, google-adsense, web-crawlers

I have set a banner before my article / content in `Wordpress` on my `single.php`. Will this be a problem if we look at it in `SEO` terms? So that `Google` can't crawl my article or crawl it less good because of this ad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a prominent Adsense ad is not an SEO problem.   Many sites that rely on organic traffic show an ad "above the fold" where it is more likely to be seen by users and generate more revenue.

It only becomes an SEO problem if the number of ads above the fold is excessive.   Google has an organic ranking algorithm that penalizes sites that have too many ads.  To avoid this penalty you should:

- Limit the number of ads above the fold to one or two.  Matt Cutts has given guidance that ads similar in size to a Post-It note should not be a problem.
- Make sure some of your content shows above the fold.   Google will penalize sites where the ads push all the content down so that users have to scroll.
- Ensure that you have enough content per page to support the number of ads on your site. Your content should take up at least 10 times the number of pixels compared to your ads.

For more information about the "too many ads above the fold" algorithm which was launched in January 2012, see this [forum thread on webmasterworld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4408779.htm).